# How to use Microsoft Composition for attributeless IoC in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, mef

Microsoft has distributed a NuGet package named "[Microsoft Composition (MEF 2)](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.composition)" allegedly to ease MEF setup for web and Windows 8 applications.

There is also a [Getting started](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=What%20is%20Microsoft.Composition?&referringTitle=Documentation) tutorial which provides a somehow vague explanation on how to make use of this thing.

Is there a more clear set of instructions or -even better- a sample solution for using Microsoft Composition in an MVC 4 web app?

Comment: How about this example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2009/04/23/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx.  this one helped me too http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=104

Comment: I'm not looking for MEF setup or MEF 2 setup. I specifically curious about this NuGet package I mentioned. So many thanks but this is not what I want.

Comment: fair enough, i used those two links to build MEF into an mvc app for modular areas and also for solving controller dependencies.  am not sure what else you would need for getting mef into mvc

Comment: Nothing special. I just saw the package in NuGet list and got curious how it is used.

Comment: that second link will show you then, the guy uses it to build up dependencies for controllers and then instantiate them using mef composition

Answer (score 0):

How about this beginners guide on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/366583/MEF-2-Preview-Beginners-Guide

Comment: It doesn't seem to be using the above mentioned package. Is it?

Comment: The article says MEF2 so I assumed so.

Comment: It is an article on the preview version of MEF2 and not the final release but I thought it might still be helpful.